# OBB Collision Response (Rotational Elastic Collision)

Tags: physics, collision-resolution

I’m making a 3D physics simulator with OBBs and Sphere Colliders. I have all the collision detection and separation working, but I’m struggling with OBB vs Sphere collision response. I have it working with a moving sphere (with rigidbody) and a fixed OBB (no rigidbody), so the sphere bounces off the cube, but how would I go about calculating the force to apply to a rigidbody OBB colliding with either a fixed sphere or rigidbody sphere?